# Running nodejs on Gen4 VPS Linux 4 CPU with WHM & cpanel

Tags: node.js, cpanel, whm, godaddy-api

I have purchased Gen4 VPS Linux 4 CPU server on godaddy with cpanel. Then i created WHM account for cpanel. Then hosted angular website to cropydeals.com doamin using file manager. CPanel IP assigned to godaddy record to run website.

https://www.cropydeals.com/index

Then i have created sub-domain with name api.cropydeals.com. in file manager folder get's created with api where uploaded nodejs project. And also created godaddy record to work api.cropydeals.com url.

https://api.cropydeals.com/

Then with the help of SSH (Putty) i login as root & installed nodejs.

[image]

but still my nodejs server is not running.. Instread of running  node server.js file it is showing content in that file.

[image]

**It should run like below image**

**Note : Below is image is just for reference**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What port is your node instance running on? Typically you would use a reverse proxy via nginx to router traffic from 443 / 80 --> node Port

Otherwise, running the node server directly will need to have the port associated with it to be accessible.

Comment: I have added 8081 port in server.js file. At local when we run "npm start" command my server get's run. But on cpanel it is showing code within file..